# How can I record many data on a single user in Firebase auth?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to have a monitoring app for my thesis and i want to recorded many data every day I was planning to use the date and time for the recording everyday. its on my dashboard i want it to look like Sugar = date1,date2,date3,date4 etc.

```java
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore db4;
    Button b1;
    EditText e1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blood);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        db4 = getInstance();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        ActionBar ac = getSupportActionBar();
        ac.hide();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        final String time  = format.format(calendar.getTime());
        TextView t2 =  findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        t2.setText(time);

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat(("MMMM dd, YYYY"));
        final String date =  format1.format(calendar2.getTime());
        TextView t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView23);
        t1.setText(date);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String blood_glucose = e1.getText().toString();

                if (blood_glucose.isEmpty()){
                    e1.setError("Field is Empty");
                    e1.requestFocus();
                } else if (!blood_glucose.isEmpty()) {
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    String uid= mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    sugar answer = new sugar(date,time,blood_glucose);
                    db4.collection("Sugar").document(uid).set(answer);

                    startActivity(new Intent(Blood.this, Navbar.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options here:

1. You can record all measurements for a user in a single document. The advantage of this is that you only need to read/write one document. The disadvantage is that you'll always have to read the entire document (which may get pretty big over time), that you can't query for specific values, and that a document can be at most 1MB in size.
2. You can record each measurement for a user in a subcollection under that user's profile. The advantages and disadvantages in this case are the opposite of the previous approach. :)

---

To **store all measurements in a single document**, you need to add each measurement to the document. Your current document overwrites the existing values in the document, but you can easily merge them with the existing data with something like this:

```
sugar answer = new sugar(date,time,blood_glucose);
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("20191118", answer);
db4.collection("Sugar").document(uid).set(update, SetOptions.merge());
```

So in the above code we create a map for the new measurement. We store that measurement in a field called `20191118` (today's date), but you could also use any other field name or [store them in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
db4.collection("Sugar").document(uid).update("measurements", FieldValue.arrayUnion(answer));
```

---

To **store each measurement for a user in a subcollection for that user**, you need to write to a subcollection under the user profile. So you'd typically have something like `/Users/$uid/Measurements/$measurementid`, and then write it with something like this:

```
sugar answer = new sugar(date,time,blood_glucose);
db4.collection("users").document(uid).collection("Measurements").add(answer);
```

Now you can perform queries on a user's measurements, for example to get all measurements in a date range, or to find their higher value over a certain interval.

Comment: thx man ... really helped me i chose the second option so i did this :

db3.collection("Blood Glucose").document(uid).collection("Date").document(date).collection("Time").document(time).set(answer);

Comment: so here is another question, now that i recorded the data how can i show it in a textview ? what method will i use ?